# router.get without parameter but asking for param

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to use express nodejs and JWT. Here is the source code of what I've been through: [link](https://repl.it/repls/ViolentHilariousPup).

I protect all routes, except routes that I declare inside the jwt.js file.

1. the `'/trial'` url, is not protected. The controller is inside the`trial.controller.js` file. When I hit the url in postman, both with the `get` and the `post` method and without any auth (`No Auth`), I get what I expect.
2. But, the same things do not happen when I hit `'/users/testdata'`. It's not protected, but if I hit it with the `get` method and without any auth, it returns `error 500` with the message `"Cannot read property 'sub' of undefined"` in postman. But, when I hit it with the `post` method, I get what I expect.

So, what's wrong with the `get` method?

Please see the above link for complete code. Any help will mean a lot to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because the route `router.get('/:id', getById);` is defined before the route `router.get('/testdata', getTest);`. So when you perform a request to the `/testdata` route, it is handled by the `/:id` route, that requires authentication to work, and uses the `currentUser.sub` attribute, although the `currentUser` variable is currently undefined.

Just change the order from

```
router.get('/:id', getById);
router.get('/testdata', getTest);
```

to

```
router.get('/testdata', getTest);
router.get('/:id', getById);
```

Comment: oh man, what silly mistake lol. Thats why I love programming. Thank you, George!